# os.path.join only takes drive name from the first argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I am creating a script that involves copying some folders/files and I ran into this problem.

I need to generate a destination path by stripping down a few things from source path. Consider input user input source path to be `D:\byn\scripts\script.js` and destination path to be `C:\TEST\scripts` then the generated final path should be `C:\TEST\scripts\byn\scripts\script.js`.

I am using this code

```
import shutil, pathlib, os

dst = r"C:\TEST\scripts"    
src = pathlib.Path(r"D:\byn\scripts\script.js")     
print(os.path.splitdrive(src), os.path.splitdrive(src)[1], type(os.path.splitdrive(src)[1])   )    
print(dst, os.path.join(dst,os.path.splitdrive(src)[1] ))
```

Ideally it should return what I want but instead it returns weird output: `C:\byn\scripts\script.js`

complete output of the script:

```
 ----jGRASP exec: python test.py
('D:', '\\byn\\scripts\\script.js') \byn\scripts\script.js <class 'str'>
C:\TEST\scripts C:\byn\scripts\script.js
```

It only keeps the drive letter and discards TEST\scripts entirely. I don't know why this happening. I don't know what I am doing wrong...need help with this. Preferably, I'd like a cross-platform solution.

Comment: for windows try `os.path.join(dst,*os.path.splitdrive(src)[1].split('\\'))`

Comment: for cross platform use if else to split the path and use